# Checkbox id's are not assigning properly in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

in my laravel application, I'm loading a set of checkboxes inside a form

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

        <div class="form-group">

          
            <strong>Test List :</strong>

            <br>

            @foreach($ttype as $value)

                <label>{{ Form::checkbox('samp_list[]', $value->test_name, false, array('class' => 'name','sumT'=>''.$value->test_desc.'','id'=>'cbox'.$value->id.'','onclick'=>'myFunction()')) }}

                {{ $value->test_name }}</label>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                  function myFunction() {

                  var boxId=<?php echo''.$value->id.''; ?>  

                  console.log('cbox'+boxId);
                  // Get the checkbox
                  var checkBox = document.getElementById('cbox'+boxId);
                  // Get the output text
                  var text = document.getElementById("text");

                  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
                  if (checkBox.checked == true){
                    text.style.display = "block";
                    alert('puka');
                  } else {
                    text.style.display = "none";
                  }
                } 
                </script>

            <br/>

            @endforeach


        </div>

    </div>
```

In that code, I'm trying to assign a checkbox id into javascript's boxId variable. I'm getting all these checkbox values through the DB, even though I've included the javascript code inside my foreach loop, only the last checkbox id stores as the boxId.

If I select checkbox 1 boxId should be cbox1
if it's checkbox 2, boxId has to be cbox2....If I select the 10th checkbox then boxId has to be cbox10...

But now as for my boxId, am only getting the last checkbox id only...

Answer (score 0):

You having this behavior because each loop you're overwriting `myFunction`.

What you could do is move `myFunction` out of the loop, pass the event as parameter and get the checkbox from the event with `event.target`. Something like that...

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Test List :</strong>
        <br>
        @foreach($ttype as $value)

            <label>{{ Form::checkbox('samp_list[]', $value->test_name, false, array('class' => 'name','sumT'=>''.$value->test_desc.'','id'=>'cbox'.$value->id.'','onclick'=>'myFunction(event)')) }}

                {{ $value->test_name }}</label>

            <br/>

        @endforeach
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction(event) {
                // Get the checkbox
                var checkBox = event.target;
                // Get the output text
                var text = document.getElementById("text");

                // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
                if (checkBox.checked == true){
                    text.style.display = "block";
                    alert('puka');
                } else {
                    text.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, still the checkbox id is same for all, which is the last checkbox id for all the check boxes

Comment: But the checkbox id is not use anymore in the js code. Are you sure that each `$value` has a different id?

Comment: it is,  var boxId=<?php echo''.$value->id.''; ?>

Comment: But line has been removed, hasn't it ?